# Reproducible nix-env -i with only Nix, no NixOS

Tags: nix

I am only using `Nix` as a package manager and not using all of `NixOS`. I would  like a reproducible `nix-env -i` package installation which can be shared and backed up.

I am aware of using `config.nix` for for `NixOS` but I am looking for similar functionality with just `Nix` packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Nixpkgs you can use the `buildEnv` function to construct symlink farms similar to how `nix-env` produces them.

This lets you group packages together into groups that you want to update separately. Of course a single group is perfectly valid if that suits your applications.

Here's an example `greeting-tools.nix`:

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  inherit (pkgs) buildEnv;

in buildEnv {
  name = "greeting-tools";
  paths = [ pkgs.hello pkgs.cowsay pkgs.figlet ];
}
```

You can install it and remove it as follows

```
$ nix-env -i -f greeting-tools.nix
installing 'greeting-tools'
$ hello
Hello, world!
$ nix-env -e greeting-tools
uninstalling 'greeting-tools'
$ hello
The program ‘hello’ is currently not installed. [...]
```

To update your packages, you have to re-run the installation command. `nix-env -u` will not work correctly because that only looks at Nixpkgs, which *probably* doesn't have anything named like that.

An alternative may be [home manager](https://github.com/rycee/home-manager).

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect and much simpler than other solutions I have seen! I am using nix as my global package manager at the moment so I can definitely utilze this and just backup my install file to github.

Answer (score -1):

I'm still new, but discovered https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#sec-building-environment which should do exactly the same and what was being asked.

E.g. inside `~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix`

```
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: with pkgs; {
    myPackages = pkgs.buildEnv {
      name = "greeting-tools";
      paths = [
        hello
        cowsay
        figlet
      ];
    };
  };
}
```

And install via `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.myPackages`

Another way would be to define a new overlay, e.g. in  `~/.config/nixpkgs/overlays/greeting-tools/default.nix`:

```
self: super: {
  greetingTools = super.buildEnv {
    name = "greeting-tools";
    paths = [
      self.hello
      self.cowsay
      self.figlet
    ];
  };
}
```

Which then can be installed like any other package: `nix-env -i my-packages`